# Oracle Trigger with If Statement AND OR conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to get an oracle trigger to work.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHK_SALES_JOB 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF JOB_ID ON EMPLOYEES 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :old.department_id = 80 AND (:new.job_id != 'SA_REP' OR :new.job_id != 'SA_MAN') THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Sales Department can only have SA_MAN or SA_REP');
  END IF;
END;
```

Here's the update statement:

```
UPDATE employees
SET job_id = 'SA_REP'
WHERE employee_id = 179;
```

The problem that I'm facing at the moment is that with the if statement, it will only work like this:

```
IF :old.department_id = 80 AND :new.job_id != 'SA_REP' THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Sales Department can only have SA_MAN or SA_REP');
END IF;
```

If I have the OR condition within the If statement, the code would never work. It will compile the trigger with no problem, but when ever I try to update the employees table, it will continuously display the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace OR with NOT IN:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHK_SALES_JOB 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF JOB_ID ON EMPLOYEES 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :old.department_id = 80 AND :new.job_id NOT IN ('SA_REP', 'SA_MAN') THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Sales Department can only have SA_MAN or SA_REP');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It might have been easier just to replace the `or` with `and`.

Comment: `(:new.job_id != 'SA_REP' OR :new.job_id != 'SA_MAN')` will evaluate to true as long as one of the conditions is true.  Boolean logic indicates that `true OR false = true`, and `true AND false = false`.

Compare `NOT IN ('SA_REP', 'SA_MAN')` to the initial OR condition.  The initial condition will evaluate to true when `:new.job_id = 'SA_REP'`, since `:new.job_id != 'SA_MAN'` evaluates to true.